# PHP file upload results in broken files on Windows Apache server

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, broken-image

I have written a file upload script for PHP. I'm testing on a Windows Apache server, but it will finaly have to work on a CentOS server with Apache. Because I am still debugging, I haven't tested it on the live linux machine. Have Googled it, but can't find a good solution.

What happens? When I upload a .png or .jp(e)g file, everything is going well. The script moves my file to the right dir, but then output a non readable file. Check the image below. My upload part of the script:

```
if ($posting_photo === true) {
    $uploaded_file = $_FILES['review_photo'];
    $uploaded_file['ext'] = explode('.', $uploaded_file['name']);

    //Only continue if a file was uploaded with a name and an extension
    if ((!empty($uploaded_file['name'])) && (is_array($uploaded_file['ext']))) {
        $uploaded_file['ext'] = secure(strtolower(end($uploaded_file['ext'])));
        $upload_session = secure($_COOKIE[COOKIE_NAME_POST_REVIEW_SESSION]);
        $upload_dir = realpath(getcwd() . DIR_REVIEW_IMAGES) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $upload_session . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $upload_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        //Only continue if a file was uploaded in a right way
        if (($uploaded_file['error'] == 0) && ($uploaded_file['size'] > 0) && ($uploaded_file['size'] <= MAX_FILESIZE_REVIEW_PHOTO_BYTES) && (in_array($uploaded_file['ext'], $upload_ext))) {

            //Check if upload dir already exists. If so, there will be probably files in it. So we check for that too. If not, we can start with the first file.
            if (is_dir($upload_dir)) {
                //
                //
                //Part where a new file name gets generated. Not very interesting and it works well, so I left it out on Stack Overflow
                //
                //


            } else {
                mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);
                $upload_name = $upload_session . '-1.' . $uploaded_file['ext'];

            }


            //Check if new upload name was generated. If not, something is wrong and we will not continue
            if (!empty($upload_name)) {
                chmod($upload_dir, 0777);

                if (move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir . $upload_name)) {
                    $files = array_diff(@scandir($upload_dir), array('.', '..'));

                    //Change slashes on Windows machines for showing the image later
                    $upload_dir = str_replace('\\', '/', $upload_dir);


                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

---

All variables not initialized here are initialized earlier. The cookie is set and checked before, and is used for unique directory and file names. Check this image for the output file. The x leftunder is from Dropbox (Dropbox says: Can't sync ... access denied). The Photo Viewer window says: Cannot open this picture becasue you have no access to the file location. Viewing the file in the browser results in a permission denied.
[Link to image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9719519/Fora/screenuploadingfiles.png)

Who is familiar with this problem and/or knows a solution? Hope you can help me out here!

Comment: Check if the move_uploaded_file() function is returning true or false, your current if appears to do nothing of interest. Add an else and output success or error to the error log / screen.

Comment: Try to log or output information in places that could be the problem. Now it's just guessing what happens.

Comment: The files moved every time, so I was assuming that move_uploaded_file() returns true each time. But I checked, and it does return true. I didn't add an else to the last if statement, because php cleans removes the file from the temp folder if the scripts ends without doing anything with the uploaded file.

Comment: @Bart I printed some vars. $upload_name is returning right values, $upload_dir does exists and the created file does exists. move_uploaded_file() returns true.

Comment: I don't know how permission work exactly on Windows. But try `chmod(0777)` on the uploaded file. It should make it readable for you. Also checkout http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php which can help during file creation in a script.

Comment: @Bart Already tried that. But chmod() will be ignored on Windows, because such file permissions are only existing on Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this once too. It's a bug in PHP 5.3.x. After upgrading from 5.3.3 to 5.6 the problems were gone!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's an update about the problem... The issue described above was caused by my local server at my office. On my local server at home, the images were fine after moving. So it's not my script, but the server. I guess PHP handles something different.

PHP version at my office is version 5.4.9, PHP at home is version 5.3.3. Maybe this info can help?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I got the same problem on apache for windows

Comment: No, I haven't found an answer yet. I've updated my home server to PHP 5.5.13 recently, and it caused to do the same at my home server too. But the images are visible in browsers, so I didn't pay any more attention to it. **BUT...** I found out that when I use the uploaded file to create other images (to create thumbnails for example), the newly created images are visible. So if this issue really gives you problems, maybe you can copy the image with PHP to a new file and delete the old one to get it visible.